# Docker and Kubernetes setup

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am pretty new to containerization and after looking into k8s and docker documentation, I am not sure, if I can achieve my goal.

In real life I have 6 PCs connected in LAN, exchanging some data and showing it on monitors. I want to mimic the setup without the hardware, using Kubernetes. Note, the setup is running GUI applications, 6 monitors total with different apps on each of those. [image: real setup] Red lines indicate connections through Ethernet cable. Added IP addresses for all PCs.

So expected result would be a k8s cluster with 6 docker containers configured to talk to each other and some of those containers to be able to make use of displays.

Is it possible to recreate this setup, providing the OS are the same as on hardware or I should make some changes?
As I want to run it all on 1 PC and have 6 monitors, to show GUIs, the PC should have multiple videocards as well?
The payload per machine is not that big, so I think one 8 core processor unit might be enough?

Thanks for any insights and help.

Comment: In general, something running in a container has no particular notion of "hardware"; you cannot have a container "with 2 monitors", for example.  Especially the Kubernetes environment is _very_ different from a physical-host setup, so you can't for example simulate these two separated networks.  I'd look into a VM-based simulation of this instead.

Comment: @DavidMaze hm, i see. Thanks for answer, I expected VM to be a working solution, just thought maybe I could have solution with easier infrastructure.

Comment: You probably just want to look into some kind of cloud provider with a free tier if you want to try out simple container orchestration on Kubernetes. Have a look at https://www.architect.io/